# Parsing column data in SQL Syntax to an SQL Query

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve a business flow issue at my work and I have an idea that I hope is technically feasible in SQL. What I would like to try and do is store different formulas in SQL syntax into database columns. Within SQL queries I would set variables to equal these columns so that the content of the columns is parsed as a part of the query and the different SQL statements pops up depending on the select specifications.

*Short and sweet*: I have some widgets to sell and whether or not a client can get these widgets depends on what other widgets they have bought, should have and shouldn’t have, country, customerid, their widget version, widget category and a couple of other things.

My question is how would someone proceed with this? I’m sure someone has made a similar setup before but which methods would be useful to study for my case? Are there case studies where I can find inspiration? I have searched for this without any luck. Hopefully someone who have solved similair issues before would be able to point me in a direction.

Thanks to whom‘ever is able to answer and has had the interest to read my post.

Best regards

Zaid

Comment: If you are using ORACLE for example, you can build the SQL Statement dynamically in a PL/SQL block and then execute it. What DB are you using?

Comment: You could use Functions or Stored Procedures to hold the `formulas in SQL syntax` and use role based access groups or do a table lookup to see if the running user has permissions to execute.

Comment: Hi AeroX - thanks for your reply, I'm using a MS SQL 2008 . Could you specify some of the functions you would use? Any ways of inspiration are welcome. I have thought of using stored procedures and call these procedures in the middle of the queries just need to get my mind around it and how to go forward with it.

Answer (score 0):

**OK this is more of a comment than an answer but the formatting doesn't work if I enter it as a comment!

To very vaguely answer your question I would have a Widgets table ie

```
WidgetID | Widget Name
1          Widget1
2          Widget2
3          Widget3
4          Widget4
```

Then have a WidgetRequirements table which is

```
WidgetRequiredID | WidgetID | RequiredWidgetID
1                  1          2
2                  1          3
3                  1          4
4                  2          4 
5                  3          1
6                  3          4
```

This tells you that WidgetID 1 needs Widgets 2, 3 and 4 in order to be "active". 
Widget 2 only needs widget4 to be active and Widget3 needs widgets 1 and 4.

This should get you started, expand on this theory.

Comment: Hi Ssc456 - thanks for replying. That's a good way to go forward with this as well thanks. I was hoping on that something like this could work out: 

WidgetRequiredID           | WidgetID 
In(2,3,5) AND not in(1,6,7)| 1 

and have the content of WidgetRequiredID parsed into the SQL query depending on which Widgets were selected. I'm looking for inspiration everywhere on this.